# How to edit the default dashboard from rails gem 'rails_admin'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-admin

I'm new to the gem rails_admin. I did some research but couldn't find a specific explanation that works well.

I already setup everything, when go to localhost:3000/admin, the dashboard shows up. But how can I edit it's dashboard. I already know it's a external resource.

Link to gemfile: https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin

Comment: Dashboard, you mean the first page where progress bars are located?

Comment: can you please clarify what you want to do??

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't change or remove `Dashboard` action in rails_admin. However, you can create your custom action which located on `root`.

[Take a look at this link](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Actions#define-actions). There is a description for creation of custom actions.